# The monotouch designer package didn't load correctly

Tags: xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have installed vs 2017 enterprise and i want to create new android project when
I try to run the project this error appear and i can't see any designer preview

```
the monotouch designer package didn't load correctly
```

how can i solve this

[image]

Comment: did you try to do a repair on visual studio?

Comment: I did but still the problem exist

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?

Comment: I have the same problem in Visual Studio 2017 Community ver. 15.5.6, when I try to open Xamarin.Forms Previewer. I already noticed it in ver. 15.5.5. Upgrading didn't fix it. I reported the problem with Visual Studio Feedback.